# Como identificar o Sistema Operacional do Servidor Firebird via SQL?

Tags: firebird

Em postgresql tem-se a tabela `version` onde todos os dados que preciso, estarão nela. Ex.:

**SQL:**

```
Select * from version()
```

**Resultado:**

```
PostgreSQL 9.2.3 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (SUSE Linux) 4.8.3 20140627 [gcc-4_8-branch revision 212064], 64-bit
```

Existe algo assim em Firebird, ou algo parecido que retorne o sistema operacional e plataforma?

Comment: `SELECT rdb$get_context('SYSTEM', 'ENGINE_VERSION') 
from rdb$database;` vai retornar a versão pra vc, mas não sei se tem o OS

Comment: Pois é, eu tinha testado esse, ele retorna só a versão. mas valeu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizei o seguinte comando, para verificar o Sistema Operacional:

```
select rdb$get_context('SYSTEM', 'DB_NAME') from rdb$database
```

Com esse retorno, consigo saber se a plataforma é Windows ou Linux:

**Retorno Windows:**

```
c:/application/data/mydatabase.fdb
```

**Retorno Linux:**

```
/application/data/mydatabase.fdb
```

Com isso consigo carregar minha UDF(.dll/.so) criada em C++ que me permite executar comandos no sistema (cmd/prompt).

E com esse cara consigo pegar qualquer informação do sistema.